# How to linear transform an equation?

Tags: geometric-transform

I want to scale transform the equation (not the graph) of a circle. Specifically, I want to scale 4x by the x-axis and 3x by the y-axis. I use the following
`x^2 + y^2 == 1 /. Thread[{x, y} -> ScalingTransform[{4, 3}][{x, y}]]`
The result is 16x^2 + 9y^2 == 1 and it is wrong. How to get the correct result of (x^2)/16 + (y^2)/9 == 1?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica SE. To get started:1) take [the introductory tour now](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour),2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up [by clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge,3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work),4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Please note that transform the equation ` x^2+y^2-1==0` is the opposite of the transform of the mapping  `f[x_,y_]=x^2+y^2-1`.

Answer (score 4):

The simple

```
x^2 + y^2 == 1 /. 
 Thread[{x, y} -> ScalingTransform[{1/4, 1/3}][{x, y}]]
```

yields

> `x^2/16 + y^2/9 == 1`

Comment: This easy fix loses generality. If I want to rotate the parabola for 60 degree, the following  ```y==x^2+2x-3 /. Thread[{x, y} -> RotationTransform[Pi/3, {0,0}][{x, y}]]``` gives the equation after -60 degree rotation.  Is there a more general way to fix the rotation and scaling problem and produce the correct equation, instead of the opposite equation?

Comment: @Richard with all due respect, the question of the OP is fully answered in my opinion. `ScalingTransform` was reported to cause some unwanted behavior and I provided an answer to that. I could NOT have guessed what you mentioned in your comment as you understand. If you are interested in `RotationTransform` perhaps you could update the OP and describe that as well in a nice context -as you did for the original question- or start a new thread. I think that this is good practice for other users as well.

Comment: @Richard I'd venture the guess that `-Pi/3` would give the intended result. In general it seems that taking the inverse of transformation should give you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mixing up active and passive transformations. It looks to me that Mathematica's definition for `Thread[{x, y} ->ScalingTransform[{4, 3}][{x, y}]]` is to replace `x` with `4x` and `y` with `3y`, which is an active transformation.

In your original post, you say that you want to *"scale 4x by the x-axis and 3x by the y-axis,"* which I believe you are conceptualising as a passive transformation. The active transformation which achieves this effect is to replace `x` with `x/4` and `y` with `y/3`, as described in @kcr's answer. This change of perspective also solves your problem with `RotationTransform` in the comments.